# Comparing Single Elements in Multidimensional Arrays in Python 3

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a program in Python 3 and I'm having some trouble with multidimensional lists.

I have two multidimensional lists populated with data returning from an API call and I'd like to compare each lowest-level list of the first list with each lowest level list of the second list and if it meets certain conditions, append it to a third list.

The program will call the API and retrieve `x`.  Then in another 5 minutes, it will make the same call again and the newer values are placed in list `y`.  The comparison will be used to determine if specific values within the lists have increased. If they have, then they are appended to the third array.

Here is what each list looks like:

```
x = [
    [[x1a1, x2a1, x3a1], [x1b1, x2b1, x3b1], [x1c1,x2c1,x3c1]],
    [[x1a2, x2a2, x3a2], [x1b2, x2b2, x3b2], [x1c2,x2c2,x3c2]],
    [[x1a3, x2a3, x3a3], [x1b3, x2b3, x3b3], [x1c3,x2c3,x3c3]],
    [[x1a4, x2a4, x3a4], [x1b4, x2b4, x3b4], [x1c4,x2c4,x3c4]],
    ...
    ]

y = [
    [[y1a1, x2a1, x3a1], [y1b1, y2b1, y3b1], [y1c1,y2c1,y3c1]],
    [[y1a2, x2a2, x3a2], [y1b2, y2b2, y3b2], [y1c2,y2c2,y3c2]],
    [[y1a3, x2a3, x3a3], [y1b3, y2b3, y3b3], [y1c3,y2c3,y3c3]],
    [[y1a4, x2a4, x3a4], [y1b4, y2b4, y3b4], [y1c4,y2c4,y3c4]],
    ...
    ]
z = []
```

What I need to do is to compare all x1-prefixed elements with all y1-prefixed elements, all x2-prefixed elements with all y2-prefixed elements, and all x3-prefixed elements with all y3-prefixed elements.

The logic in my code is as follows for one comparison as a sample:

```
if x1a1 == y1a1 and x3a1 == y3a1 and x2a1 > y2a1:
    z.append([y1a1,y2a1,y3a1])
else:
    #Do Nothing
```

I need to run the above comparison for every single grouping of three variables (i.e. `[x1a1, x2a1, x3a1]` and `[y1b3, y2b3, y3b3]`, etc) and I'd like to avoid multiple nested for loops if I can.

Any guidance in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first flatten your lists, we can use generators since we just want them to find the product intersections of the two lists

```
x_flat = (item for row in x for item in row)
y_flat = (item for row in y for item in row)
```

now just check all the products of x and y tuples

```
z = [x_test for x_test,y_test in itertools.product(x_flat,y_flat) if x_test == y_test]
```

you should not have to check each element of the lists assuming `x1a1` or whatever behaves like a normal python object

```
[1,2,3] == [1,2,3] # True
```